# How to get value of EditText after it has been edited by a user?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have created an EditText "quantity" which has a default value of 1. I want to get the final value of EditText "quantity" after the user edited it instead of giving me the default value (= 1).

How can I do that from here?

```html
EditText quantity = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.quantity);
final int qty = Integer.valueOf(quantity.getText().toString()).intValue();

quantity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

Comment: get value of `s` from  `afterTextChanged(..)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get updated value from `afterTextChanged(Editable s)`

```
     @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
             try{
                qty = Integer.valueOf(s.toString()).intValue();
             }catch(Exception e){
               ///
             }
        }
```

Comment: i already tried this but variable qty says "cannot assign a value to final variable "qty" what should i do? @Rustam

Comment: make `qty` as non final class variable. because you can not change final variable value.

Comment: sorry im new in programing what do you mean by that ...?

Comment: put  `int qty;` outside `onCreate()`

Comment: @jeiidii if you are using a variable in anonymous inner class it needs to be final.  Quoting java docs An anonymous class cannot access local variables in its enclosing scope that are not declared as final or effectively final. You could declare it as a instance variable